# GraphX pregel and spark streaming: the RDDs pushed into the rddQueue within the vprog are not processed

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

I am using the GraphX pregel and the spark streaming. I want that the vertex program (the vprog) creates a RDD and pushes it into the rddQueue to be processed.

```
val queueOfRDDs:Queue[RDD[Int]] = Queue.empty[RDD[Int]]        
@transient val streamingContext:StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))    
val inputDStream = streamingContext.queueStream(queueOfRDDs,true,null)
inputDStream.map(x => (x % 10, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).print()
streamingContext.start()

val initialMessage = "init"

def vertexProgram(id: VertexId, attr: String, msgs: String): String =
  {
    queueOfRDDs.synchronized {
      for(a <- 1 to 3) {
        queueOfRDDs.+=sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000, 10)
        println("will add " + queueOfRDDs.size)
      }
    }
    msgs
  }

  def sendMessage(...){...}
  def messageCombiner(...){...}
  val newGraph = Pregel.apply(graph,initialMessage,1,EdgeDirection.Out)(vertexProgram,sendMessage,messageCombiner)
```

The expected result is:

```
will add1
    will add2
    will add3
    will add4
    will add5
    will add6
    will add7
    ...
    -------------------------------------------
    Time: 1503048820000 ms
    -------------------------------------------
    (0,100)
    (6,100)
    (3,100)
    (9,100)
    (4,100)
    (1,100)
    (7,100)
    (8,100)
    (5,100)
    (2,100)

    -------------------------------------------
    Time: 1503048820000 ms
    -------------------------------------------
    (0,100)
    (6,100)
    (3,100)
    (9,100)
    (4,100)
    (1,100)
    (7,100)
    (8,100)
    (5,100)
    (2,100)

    ...

    -------------------------------------------
    Time: 1503048820000 ms
    -------------------------------------------
    (0,100)
    (6,100)
    (3,100)
    (9,100)
    (4,100)
    (1,100)
    (7,100)
    (8,100)
    (5,100)
    (2,100)
```

But I got this result:

```
    will add1
    will add2
    will add3
    will add4
    will add5
    will add6
    will add7
    ...
```

The RDDs are pushed into the queueOfRDDs (its size increased) but they are not processed.
Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: This cannot work.

This code doesn't look right. It looks like you are trying to create initialize RDD from within task (`vertexProgram`), probably by making `SparkContext` lazy or using object wrapper.

Your program appends to a local copy of the `Queue` which is not visible for the actual driver program. Even if it was `RDDs` would correspond to different contexts.